# Scrapy how to output the data in organized way

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

Recently I have been working on one project which scrapes one website.
The steps which my spider is following are:

1. Goes to the main problem site and extract all the link available (a,b,c,d)
2. After getting links it will follow each link one by one and goes to their status page where there is data.
3. Before going to status page it will pass one query in url to get desired data. So in total I will have to visit status page twice with different queries. Example: https://example.com?language=14, https://example.com?language=15 just like that.
4. On status page sometimes there are more than one page (?page=1, ?page=2 and many queries). So if there are more result on status page then it must goes to the next page and scrape the given data.

After everything is done it must return the data in organized way for example:

{'data': '1', 'status_page_data': {'14': [1,2,3], '15' [4,5,6]}

Here [1,2,3] is the data extracted from status page by going each page one by one with query '14'.

And like this. But in my case I am getting my data like:

{'data': '1', 'status_page_data': {'14': [], '15' []}

{'data': '1', 'status_page_data': {'14': [], '15' [4,5,6]}

It is repeating every time. One thing is sure that I am doing something wrong with yield but I am not sure what it is.

**I want my data to be returned once with all the data available and scrapped**

Sample code:

```
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self):

        self.lang = {'114': ' GO', '20': ' D'}
        self.temp = ''

    name = 'codespider'

    # URL to start scrapping
    start_urls = ['URL']

    def getAnswer(self, response):
        data = response.meta['data']
        a = response.css('tbody')

        '''
        This for loop is used to append data if found else passed
        self.temp is the paramter passed
        '''
        for i in a.css('tr'):
            try:
                data['answer'][self.temp].append(i.css('td::text').extract()[0])
            except:
                pass

        #If next page is found then go on scraping else move out from there
        if ('/sites/all/themes/abessive/images/page-next-active.gif' in response.text):
            ans = 'STATUS_URL_PAGE_2'
            yield scrapy.Request(url = ans, callback = self.getAnswer, meta = {'data': data})

        #After everything is done yield all the data
        yield data

    def parse(self, response):

        '''
        First extract all the links from the page

        '''
        for link in response.css('tr.problemrow'):
            # Items created
            data = {}
            data['name'] = link.css('div.problemname b::text').extract()[0]
            data['code'] = link.css('td a::text').extract()[2]
            data['successfully_submission'] = link.css('td div::text').extract()[2]
            data['accuracy'] = link.css('td a::text').extract()[3]
            data['answer'] = {}

            '''

            With given link extracted follow each link status page to extract answer
            self.lang.keys here used to pass parameters on URL to get that desired output
            And later can be scrapped to append in data['answer']
            '''
            for i in self.lang.keys():
                ans = 'STATUS_PAGE_URL'
                self.temp = i
                yield scrapy.Request(url = ans, callback = self.getAnswer, meta = {'data': data})
```

Comment: yield is async, so it might be executed before all the page scraped. I suggest that just yield every data per request and save them to csv. Do ETL later to aggregate all the data to format you want.